# Excel comments not being pasted after copy

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to copy and paste comments from one Excel workbook to another, but **the comments don't get pasted after being copied from the first workbook**.

Here is my code:

```
  Sub Comments()
    Dim x As Workbook
    Dim y As Workbook

    Set x = Workbooks.Open("C:\Exportbook.xlsx")
    Set y = ActiveWorkbook

    x.Sheets("Tablets").Range("E10:AQ2000").Copy
    y.Sheets("Tablets").Range("E10:AQ2000").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteComments

    x.Close SaveChanges:=False

  End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use **ThisWorkbook** instead of **ActiveWorkbook**.

Currently your code copies and pastes from/to the same location. After opening workbook x it will become the active workbook, so workbook y is the same as workbook x.

Comment: The vb script is in the active workbook and it is a different file.  The vb script will run on open

Comment: You need to use ThisWorkbook instead of ActiveWorkbook.

Comment: @user2220670 - Is this `VB Script` or is it `VBA`? There are important differences...

Comment: Greg, I missed your comment about ThisWorkbook.  I just saw it and used it and it worked.  Thanks a lot.